# PuppeteerSharp is changing date format got from textContent

Tags: javascript, .net, date, puppeteer

So I have a bit of a problem, this is how the html part looks:

`<span class="element">date: </span>2021-08-18T08:38:48.956`

So I want to get the date after `</span>` tag, but Puppeteer changes format even if I'll get the date as textContent

Here is part of my code:

```
string dateXpath = "//span[text()='date: ']/following-sibling::text()";
var dateElement = await _page.WaitForXPathAsync(dateXpath);
var dateTextElement = await dateElement.GetPropertyAsync("textContent");
string date = dateTextElement.ToString();
```

Expected `date = JSHandle:2021-08-18T08:38:48.956`

Result `date = JSHandle:18.08.2021 08:38:48`

Is there any way to bypass Puppeteer's JS changing the date?

@update

```
_page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>("e => e.textContent", dateElement);
```

Gives: `08/18/2021 08:38:48`

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
string dateXpath = "//span[text()='date: ']/following-sibling::text()";
var dateElement = await _page.WaitForXPathAsync(dateXpath);
DateTime date = _page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<DateType>("e => e.textContent", dateElement);
date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss")
```

This is why my solution didn't work (i think):

Puppeteer parsed that whole string to DateTime when I was getting it by:
`_page.EvaluateFunctionAsync`

Then it parsed formatted DateTime back to string, cuz i wanted a string: `_page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<string>`

So the solution to that problem is getting DateTime instead of string, and parse it to string with our format `("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss")`